# I want to create multiple subnets in multiple virtual networks using terraform and variables

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Example:
I want to create 2 vnets using variables and create 2 subnets one vnet and 3 subnets in one vnet.

Comment: Thanks man @Charles Xu, it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, the example code here:

```
variable "vnet_address_space" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "subnet_prefix" {
    default = [
        "10.0.1.0/24",
        "10.0.2.0/24"
    ]

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "testResourceGroup1"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "acceptanceTestVirtualNetwork1"
  address_space       = ["${var.vnet_address_space}"]
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  count                = "${length(var.subnet_prefix)}"
  name                 = "testsubnet-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}"
  address_prefix       = "${element(var.subnet_prefix, count.index)}"
}
```

You can create another Vnet in the same format and change something in it as you wish.